# about vector in c++

Tags: c++, stl

i wanna make a function that generates a list of random numbers with a size inserted by the user to apply some sorting algorithms on these randoms why this code doesn't run ..plz help

```
vector<int> DataList; 

int GenerateRandomList(int min, int max, int size)
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        DataList[i]=rand()% max+min;
        cout<<DataList[i];
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Please format code so it is readable.

Comment: Please re-format your code, we can't read it.

Comment: What does "doesn't run" mean? What happens when you run it?

Answer (score 4):

Your vector is empty, you cannot assign to non-existing elements.

Simply replace `DataList[i] = ...` with `DataList.push_back(...)` and it should work.

Also, `rand() % max + min` will not do what you want, because there are only `max - min + 1` numbers between `min` and `max` (inclusive). `rand() % (max - min + 1) + min` should work.

Also, `srand` should be called once at the beginning of `main` and then never again. Otherwise, you may get the same sequence of numbers if you call `GenerateRandomList` twice in a row.

Also, why is the function declared to return an `int`? You should either change that to `void` or `std::vector<int>` and return the numbers you just generated instead of having a global vector.

Comment: Also no point in having the "cout << endl" as a seperate statement. I'd just do "cout << DataList[i] << endl;

Comment: @Stealth Rabbi: The `endl` itself is dumb. It should be `'\n'`. And `cout` should probably be `cerr` (which makes the flushing completely superfluous) since I think this is debugging output.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this is by using [`std::generate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate/). The example on the linked page covers your problem.

In your particular case, you would have to use a functor:

```
struct GenerateRandomList {
    GenerateRandomList(int min, int max)
    : min(min), max(max)
    {
        srand(time(NULL)); 
    }

    int operator()() const { 
        // this is courtesy of @FredOverflow's answer
        return rand() % (max - min + 1) + min; 
    }
private:
    int min;
    int max;
};

// for generating
std::vector<int> DataList(10);
std::generate(DataList.begin(), DataList.end(), GenerateRandomList(10, 20));
```

You can see a working example [here](http://ideone.com/mXbOL). The advantage of this approach is, that you can generate random numbers for any kind of container (arrays, lists, vectors, sets).

Comment: While I think you're right, at this person's skill level, I don't think that answer will help them much. :-(

Comment: @Omnifarious: I am merely giving him the opportunity to learn. It is his choice to take it or not.

Comment: +1: It's never too early to learn better ways of doing things with STL

Comment: That's a good sentiment, and I won't disagree. However, if you want him to learn, you should pick a better name for `GenerateRandomList`. Perhaps `RangedRandomNumberGenerator` or something. The class does not generate a list and so the name is confusing.

Comment: I'd take `std::srand()` out of the ctor. I'd assume `main()` takes care of that. Less code, faster, more correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you want to do push_back(int) instead of doing DataList[i]=rand()% max+min;.  The following code compiles and does exactly what i think you are trying to do.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<int> DataList;
int GenerateRandomList(int min, int max, int size) {
   srand ( time(NULL) );
   for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
     DataList.push_back(rand()% max+min);
    cout<<DataList[i];
    cout<<endl;
   }
}


int main() {
  GenerateRandomList(0,15,10);
}
```